# Formless VB.Net - Overrides Sub in Module?

Tags: vb.net, module, overriding

i coded a WindowsFormApplication which handles basic updating processes and USB detection via windows messages and here comes the problem. In a form it´s no problem to have a "Protected Overrides Sub WndProc" like mine :

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        ' >>>>Process USB Insertion<<<<
        If m.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then
            If CInt(m.WParam) = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL Then
                Dim DeviceInfo As DEV_BROADCAST_HDR
                DeviceInfo = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_HDR)), DEV_BROADCAST_HDR)
                If DeviceInfo.dbch_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME Then
                    Dim Volume As DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME
                    Volume = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)), DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)
                    Driveletter = (GetDriveLetterFromMask(Volume.dbcv_unitmask) & ":\")
```

Is there a way to include that in a Module so i can build a formless application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from spinning your own message loop (using direct calls to GetMessage / TranslateMessage / DispatchMessage).  This is how the Microsoft COM server example code works.  In particular, I'd recommend looking at ExeCOMServer.vb and NativeMethod.vb; the main sub in this example just calls ExeCOMServer.Instance.Run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow class is the base class of a window. Using this class, you can use a function named AssignHandle which takes one parameter, the HWND of the object (control). And you have to override a method named WndProc. So, there is no WndProc without a Form.

Comment: Is there any way to achive my goal? I really need to catch both USB detection message and shutdown message from Windows.